# Update sqlite database using variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code to update values in a table. When I run the code I get the error `near "(": syntax error`.

This is my code:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE playerList SET (gamesPlayed, totalPTS, totalREB, totalAST, totalSTL, totalTO, totalBLK, ftMade, ftAttempts, fgMade, fgAttempts, threeptMakes, threeptAttempts) = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE playerCode = (?)', (newGp, newTotPts, newTotReb, newTotAst, newTotStl, newTotTo, newTotBlk, newFtMade, newFtAttempt, newFgMade, newFgAttempt, newThreePointMade, newThreePointAttempt, code))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You might want to stick to the columname = value syntax since it makes easier to see if you've made a mistake matching things up somewhere and can be formatted sanely (as in, not all on one giant line)

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback) in question

Comment: find SQL tutorial and check `UPDATE` syntax - as for me it is incorrect. Or run you query directly in database and you should get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Row values are supported only in SQLite 3.15.0 or later. If you have an earlier version (which is likely with any current Python version), you have to use the standard SQL syntax, which is [documented in the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).